# SITE URL ABBREVIATION .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

site url How to shorten with .htaccess example: https://faydalibilimim.com/public/musteridestek instead https://faydalibimisim.com/support how do i

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it using .htaccess . But you can do it using virtual hosts file

Add this line in your virtual hosts file of your website

```
Alias /support /public/musteridestek
```

you should write this before the closing tag of virtual host ()

It will look something like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  #some code that is already present

  Alias /support /public/musteridestek
</VirtualHost>
```

if all your data in your virtual host is only comments (i.e., # infront of every line) then copy and paste the above code in the bottom of the file